# Is there a better way to use Castle Windsor's API for Factories?

Tags: castle-windsor, structuremap, ninject, factory-pattern

I am open to other IoC containers, such as NInject and StructureMap if they are much cleaner than this.  I hear that StructureMap just introduced "containers" that may simplify this , perhaps?

As the title says, is there a better way?  This seems like a lot of code, just to register an object that requires a factory to create it.

```
// The process to register an object, with a factory method
var cfg = new MutableConfiguration(p.Name);
cfg.Attributes["factoryId"] = p.TypeFactory.Name;
cfg.Attributes["factoryCreate"] = "Create";
var model = _container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.BuildModel(
    p.Name, p.TypeService, p.Type, null);
model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Pooled;
model.Configuration = cfg;
_container.Kernel.AddCustomComponent(model);
```

Versas the "non-factory" way of adding a component:

```
// registering a component with no factory method
_container.AddComponentLifeStyle(
    p.Name, p.TypeService, p.Type, LifestyleType.Singleton);
```

The first seems overly complex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you consider checking the documentation before posting this? http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API#FluentRegistrationAPI-Usingadelegateascomponentfactory:

Comment: plus also FactorySupportFacility class has methods to aid this if you don't want the fluent API. You basically chose the least optimal way of doing this.

Comment: Hello Krzysztof and thank you for the comments. Funny, I have never seen a link to castle documentation - as any links there are go to pages like this: http://api.castleproject.org/ Straight from their website.  Thank you for linking me to the actual documention (but please be kinder in your comments in the future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to register (what's `p` in the first code block?) but with  [`UsingFactoryMethod`](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API#FluentRegistrationAPI-Usingadelegateascomponentfactory:), factory registration is a breeze. Sample code:

```
container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>()
   .Register(
      Component.For<IMyService>()
         .UsingFactoryMethod(() => MyLegacyServiceFactory.CreateMyService())
         .LifeStyle.Pooled
   );
```

Comment: Hello again Mauricio! Wow, that does simplify things. As a comment to the question above mentioned, there seems to be a different place for documention, even though the main castleproject site points you to this: http://api.castleproject.org/ Thank you. Marked as answer. Oh, and the "p" was from an Linq query.  shouldn't have mattered.

Comment: IOU the download page improvement. I haven't forgotten :)